# After going live with my static page the images disappear or display in a poor quality

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-hosting

I have been working on my wedding page as a starter project. It is a simple parallax site with lots of images. Only Html, CSS and a bit Javascript were used (imported).

On my local server everything seems to be working fine. Unfortunately after uploading and opening the site it just becomes a mess. All the images are either displayed in disastrous quality or simply disappear. I have tried multiple browsers, re-uploaded the files, checked the file paths but can't figure out the problem. Chrome Dev console shows errors regarding the images:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Web host: iPage
FTP: filezilla

The images are all JPEG.

Here is the link to the landing page: http://zsizsiszabi.com/

Comment: double check your paths, that is probably why you are getting 404's. Are these images supposed to be distorted like this? Is it some artistic thing, these bars?

Comment: Are you able to download the images from an administrator console or view the file size? Then you can verify that the images are changed, which seems likely.

Comment: The site is too slow to be usable. On my connection, the site downloaded 49M (!) over 1.39 minutes. The images cannot be described as poor quality though (e.g. out of focus, fuzzy, excessive lossy artefacts) - they are just corrupted. See the blocky chunks on [this image](http://zsizsiszabi.com/English/ism/image/slides/_u/1544619655868_34681.jpeg) - it needs reuploading. Perhaps your FTP client needs to be set to binary mode?

Comment: (The question as it stands is off-topic, since it is entirely reliant on an external link. Please upload an example image to keep it from being put on hold).

Comment: I have checked the file paths. With Atomic Live Server everything is running smoothly. No corrupted images, no problem with the markup... I hope its just the uploading process. What is "binary mode"? I am using fileZilla. Its a 160 MB page. How can I make it faster?

Comment: Zoltan, your images are far too large for the web. You need to compress all of the images to optimize for the web. If the whole site is 160mb, I would imagine most of that data is coming from all of your images. As halfer mentioned, with a slow connection that will be incredibly painful for your end user. If someone is accessing the site on a mobile device using a mobile network that could use a huge portion of their data (depending on data plan) If you have Photoshop you can compress the images for the web. There are other free programs that can do this too (example: https://pnggauntlet.com)

Comment: To help with the images getting corrupted, you can try this: Open FileZilla settings, navigate to Transfers - File types, and disable "Treat files without extension as ASCII file". Then try uploading the files again, see if that helps with the corrupted images.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the missing images, for example:

> GET http://zsizsiszabi.com/Images/Denmark/treasure-map.png 404 (Not
>   Found)

This says image `treasure-map.png` can't be found in this path, and looking on the `img` tag you used to show this image:

```
<img src="../Images/Denmark/treasure-map.png" id="treasure" alt="">
```

You telling browser, "I'm expecting this image to be found by going one folder up and then go to folders `/Images/Denmark`", is it there ?

Regarding the corrupted images, they uploaded incorrectly, something happened through the upload that corrupted the images or you used a wrong settings in the FTP app, look at this image:
http://zsizsiszabi.com/English/ism/image/slides/_u/1544619616573_87463.jpeg
It's not because the site, it's because of the upload process.

Comment: I have double checked the file paths on my desktop and everything is working just fine (using Atom live server). If the paths weren't good I would get the same results. The directory uploaded contains the files in the same order. The FTP is filezilla... can't get a hold of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with an image referenced in your css. For instance look at your parallax1 css selector/rule. This css code snippet is what I am seeing in the dev tools.

Are you using a webpack/babel with any css plugins? Perhaps something is breaking during the bundling/export process.

I would go back and look at your CSS. Make sure the pathing is correct for all instances where your images don't load. If that all looks right, it could be something is going wrong with the bundling process...

```css
.parallax1 {
    background-image: url(../Images/Abo{ background-image: url(../Images/About/intro.jpg);
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, the snipet you sent (parallax1) is not the same as the original. It seems to have changed while uploading the directory.

Comment: i am using a JS image slder plug in and a weather widget but they are working fine on my local server. It must be the FTP...

Comment: Are you using webpack/babel?